# How to open camera inside ionic custom app

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing custom app using Ionic and Typescript.

Where I want to open camera and take picture, I am able to open camera from my app but the problem is, it is opening the native camera and which is coming out from my app.
What I want is open camera inside from my app, may be in Div container (which has predefined width and height)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third-party plugin [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview). Which provides powerful features, including set a custom size(position) for camera preview box.